# what other index fund captures the wilshire 5000

Tags: stocks

what other index fund captures the wilshire 5000 that isn't above $10,000.

in other words, i'm looking for Wilshire 5000, but having points similar to SPY. I just don't have the physical cash of $20,000 to buy something like W5000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up Index and Index Fund.

An Index Fund tracks an Index. SPX is the S&P 500 Index, currently at 2087.39, SPY is the ETF Index Fund that tracks SPX, SPY is currently at $208.61 per share. You are only required to buy 1 share.

W5000 is the index representing total market. You can't buy the index and its use is obsolete. You can instead buy an ETF Index Fund (e.g. VTI at $107.77) that tracks the CRSP US Total Market Index .

Comment: thanks, is there a list to the list of index funds?

Comment: @user22910 [ETFdb ETF Screener](http://etfdb.com/screener/) Over 1600 Passive ones.